# templating JSF 2.0 Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jboss, primefaces

So I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"               
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:outputText value="Test!!!" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

as my main page on my website and on template.xhtml:

```
<div id="content">
     <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="centercss">  
    <ui:insert name="content" />
 </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

...in the middle of the footer and the header views.

Now if I try to change the template="template.xhtml" to template.jsf it does not appear anywhere... the way it is right now I get my 'content' page perfectly in the middle of header and footer on the eclipse preview, but on the browser there's no content at all.

Im using primefaces3.1.1 and I have javax.faces-2.1.14 + jsf-api and jsf-impl, so I think its primefaces 3 and JSF 2.
What is the problem here ?

Comment: What's your `web.xml` setup? Is `*.jsf` registered as mapping for the servlet?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to change `template.xhtml` to `template.jsf`, which is a non-existent file? How exactly does using `template.xthml` fail for you? The solution is definitely not to change the extension like that.

Comment: Yes, it is mapping *.jsf and BalusC on the eclipse preview of main.xhtml it is on the right place, between footer and header and showing the content, but on the template.xhtml its not. The UI insert content is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using facelets (templating) in a wrong way. You should'nt have html and body tags on your main page. The page that will use the template must be defined in a `<ui:composition>` tag, and the template shall define the page as a whole (html, body, head tags, etc).

Example:

index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputText value="Test!!!" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"               
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:body>
    <div id="content">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="background-color: red;">
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```